# Multiple data streams for web + app property

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-hosting

I am new to google analytics and noticed that my firebase app was auto linked to a property in my google analytics account as type app + web.

In the data streams section of this property, I would like to ensure data comes through via two sources, `www.` and `admin.`. How do I achieve this? The UI on analytics only lets me link one web stream. I also don't seem to be able to edit this once it is set up.

I would actually prefer to set up two separate properties, as they are two different "apps", however in Firebase in Settings > Integrations > Manage you can only link one google property ID.

Both `www`. and `admin.` are hosting on the same firebase project, as separate web apps.

Where am I going wrong?